# Need help coding ODEs with minimum values in R

Tags: r, numerical-methods, ode, numerical-integration

I'm working on a phytoplankton resource model for my thesis. To get familiar with the model, I started working with ODEs for one species (of phytoplankton) and one resource (such as phosphorus). I got the analytical solutions and numerical simulations running for that.

Analytical Solutions:

```
q <- function(inputs) {
  g <- inputs[3]
  r <- inputs[2]
  d <- inputs[1]
  return((g*r)/(r-d))
}

s <- function(inputs) {
  g <- inputs[3]
  r <- inputs[2]
  d <- inputs[1]
  k <- inputs[5]
  v <- inputs[4]
  return(-(d*g*k*r)/(d*g*r+d*v-r*v))
}

n <- function(inputs) {
  g <- inputs[3]
  r <- inputs[2]
  d <- inputs[1]
  k <- inputs[5]
  v <- inputs[4]
  s0 <- inputs[6]
  (d - r)*(-1*(s0/(g*r)) - (d*k)/(d*g*r + d*v - r*v))
}
```

Numerical Simulations:

```
library(deSolve)
library(tidyverse)
one <- function (t, x, params) {
  ## first extract the state variables
  N <- x[1]
  Q <- x[2]
  S <- x[3]
  ## now extract the parameters
  r <- params["r"]
  g <- params["g"]
  d <- params["d"]
  v <- params["v"]
  k <- params["k"]
  s0 <- params["s0"]
  
  
  ## now code the model equations
  dNdt <- N*(r*(1-(g/Q))-d)
  dQdt <- v*(S/(S+k))-r*(Q-g)
  dSdt <- d*(s0-S)-(N*v*(S/(S+k)))
  ## combine results into a single vector
  dxdt <- c(dNdt,dQdt,dSdt)
  ## return result as a list!
  list(dxdt)
}
parms <- c(r=0.1, g=0.001, d=0.03, v=0.1, k=0.01, s0=1) 
times <- seq(from=0,to=1000,by=0.1)
xstart <- c(N=800,Q=1,S=1)

ode(
  func=one,
  y=xstart,
  times=times,
  parms=parms,
) %>%
  as.data.frame() -> out

out %>%
  gather(variable,value,-time) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=time,y=value,color=variable))+
  geom_line(size=2)+
  theme_classic()+ 
  labs(x='time',y='?')


### setting up dataframe with numerical simulation

## List of parameter values
l <- list(r = 0.1, 
          g = 0.001,
          d = c(0.03, 0.035, 0.04, 0.045, 0.05, 0.055, 0.06, 0.065, 0.07, 0.075,
                0.08, 0.085, 0.09),
          v = 0.1,
          k = 0.01,
          s0 = 1)

## Matrix with 'prod(lengths(l))' rows listing combinations
## of parameter values
P <- as.matrix(do.call(expand.grid, l))

## Wrapper around 'ode' extracting state at final time
getLast <- function(parms, y, times, func, ...) {
  X <- deSolve::ode(y, times, func, parms, ...)
  X[nrow(X), -1L]
}

## Matrix of final states corresponding rowwise to 'P'
X <- t(apply(P, MARGIN = 1L, FUN = getLast, 
             y = c(N = 800, Q = 1, S = 1), 
             times = seq(from = 0, to = 1000, by = 1),
             func = one))

cbind(P, X) |> as.data.frame() -> dilution
## setting up dataframe of analytical solutions

analytical <- data.frame(d = seq(0.01, 0.09, 0.005), r = rep(0.1,17), g = rep(0.001,17),
                         v = rep(0.1, 17), k = rep(0.01, 17), s0 = rep(1, 17))

analytical$qa <- apply(analytical, 1, q)
analytical$na <- apply(analytical, 1, n)
analytical$sa <- apply(analytical, 1, s)

## merge analytical and numerical simulation together

total <- merge(analytical, dilution, by = c("r", "d", "g", "k", "v", "s0"))
```

Then I merged them and plotted to compare the numerical simulations and analytical solutions (to ensure that they are equal). Now, I'm trying to add another resource to model one species, two resources, so one of the resources will be limiting. The equations for this are from a paper: [equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OziwU.png) and the equation that determines which resource is limiting is here: [limiting resource equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bajS.png)

My advisor already did the simulations and solved the analytical solutions in Mathematica, I'm trying to translate it to R but I'm still kind of new to R. I'm trying to get it to look like this: [mathematica notebook equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngi82.png) but in R. I think the equations for Q1, Q2, S1, and S2 are pretty straightforward and similar to the one species one resource that I've already done, but I'm struggling with incorporating the minimum value in the N equation. Also, would this change how I run the numerical simulation? My advisor says the numerical simulation would be easier to code so I'm wondering what makes that analytical solution for this harder to do? I appreciate any and all help!!! Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to start with some "toy examples" first, before implementing the full model. Here a model with two species (X1, X2) and two limiting substrates (S1, S2). The substrate dependency is formulated as Monod function (equivalent to Holling II). Note also the unit conversion factors `y` between the substrates and the populations.

```r
library(deSolve)

model <- function (time, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)), {
    f <- function(S, k) S/(k + S) # functional response

    grow1 <- r1 * min(f(S1, k11), f(S2, k12)) * X1
    grow2 <- r2 * min(f(S1, k21), f(S2, k22)) * X2

    dS1 <- -1/y11 * grow1 -1/y12 * grow2
    dS2 <- -1/y21 * grow1 -1/y22 * grow2
    dX1 <- grow1
    dX2 <- grow2

    list(c(dS1, dS2, dX1, dX2), 
         lim1 = f(S1, k11) < f(S2, k12), # indicates which resource is limiting
         lim2 = f(S1, k21) < f(S2, k22))
  })
}

y0     <- c(S1 = 1, S2 = 1,         # two substrates
            X1 = 1, X2 = 1)         # two populations
parms  <- c(r1 = 0.1, r2=0.12,      # maximum growth rates
            k11 = 0.12, k12 = 0.08, # half saturation constants
            k21 = 0.08, k22 = 0.12,
            y11 = 5, y12 = 1,       # yield ratios (=unit conversion factors)
            y21 = 5, y22 = 1)

times  <- seq(0, 100)
out <- ode(y0, times, model, parms)
plot(out)
```

The simulation shows how limitation of the two species switches between resources:

[image: resource switch]

For more species and substrates, one shod consider vectorization. A very compact way would be the Gujer-Peterson matrix approach, available for example in package **rodeo**.